# Game Engine's bad visualization with layers

Tags: game-engine

I'm using a score layer above a game layer.
The score layer is a Dynamic Text Display, coded in python.

The problem:

When I start game engine (press 'p' at keyboard) in the score layer *alone*, I got this visualization:

[image]

But, oddly, when I'm executing the two layers together, I got this visualization:

[image]

Instead of show the zeros, show @s!

As a score, it works correctly.
But, instead of show any number, show always @s. Score working:

[image]

What is going on?

Comment: Sharing the code could help us figure out. also maybe a .blend file.

Comment: The dynamic text was programmed like this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GKO4jfAHtjk (too much lines to share here). This is an plan, with an image uv .tga associated (arial font, in case), and works with a sensor, a logic controller and a property actuator. The actuator assign the property value. The value comes from a python code, a module associated with controller.

Comment: In the material settings, when game engine is active have you turned on the text option in the game settings? look about 3 mins into the video.

Comment: Yes, I've made every step.