# How to make dynamic text in GE?

Tags: texturing, game-engine, materials, text-object

I don't know why, but it doesn't work. I've done **everything** said in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GKO4jfAHtjk)
video, and my result is the following: planes without a transparent background, only displaying `@` as the texture, sitting next to each other. Also, there are *a lot* more planes than the text.

**I have a .blend which can be found [here](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/36646).**

Comment: A .blend file would be helpful

Comment: Duplicate of your problem? unfortunatrly no answer. http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24264/game-engines-bad-visualization-with-layers

Answer (score 1):

Your blend file did not contain the packed font image file, so I replaced the texture with one I googled.
With your plane selected, and switching to edit mode the uv/image editor showed your unwrap as this:
[image]

For dynamic text to work you need to enclose the @ symbol in your unwrap like this:
[image]

This change makes your blendfile work as intended for me.

Comment: I have done that, I don't know why that didn't show up for you. I will try again.

Comment: Well, in the first picture, where *the @ symbol wasn't wrapped*, that was intended. I had **a different character map** where the @ symbol was over there, very small.

Comment: And here is my result: http://recordit.co/E839r4i8qf